# Date format on the UI with react and how to solve it

Tags: reactjs, datetime, localization

when I run the app in UI I see two input one is "from" and one is "to" and the type is date. and the default value in the backend is "2016-01-01 00:00:00,2022-04-15 23:59:59", but it is a dynamic value. but I receive this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlOZJ.png) and If u see it considered HH:MM for from but HH:MM:SS and the format in the backend is also : HH:MM:SS

this is the code that I wrote:

```
const handleInputChange = (val, id, column, type) => {

    let formattedVal = val;
    if (type.toLowerCase() === "datetime-local") {
      formattedVal = formattedVal.replace("T", " ") + ":00";
    }
    let pRB = { ...postRequestBody };
    pRB[selectedReport.report_id] = {
      ...pRB[selectedReport.report_id],
      [id]: formattedVal,
    };
    dispatch(setPostRequestBody(pRB));
  };
```

and also :

```
 case "date":
      if (isRange) {
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
            }}
          >
            <div style={{ width: "48%" }}>
              <label htmlFor={id+'1'}>From</label>
              <TextInput
                error={errorFileds.includes(id + "1")}
                id={id + "1"}
                type={"datetime-local"}
                step={1}
                isTextArea={inputFieldSettings[id]?.isTextArea}
                value={postRequestBody[selectedReport.report_id][id + "1"]}
                handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
                placeholder="From"
                inputProps={{
                  min: min.replace(" ", "T"),
                  max: max.replace(" ", "T"),
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div style={{ width: "48%" }}>
              <label htmlFor={id + "2"}>To</label>
              <TextInput
                error={errorFileds.includes(id + "2")}
                id={id + "2"}
                type={"datetime-local"}
                step={1}
                isTextArea={inputFieldSettings[id]?.isTextArea}
                value={postRequestBody[selectedReport.report_id][id + "2"]}
                handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
                placeholder="To"
                inputProps={{
                  min: min.replace(" ", "T"),
                  max: max.replace(" ", "T"),
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }

      return (
        <TextInput
          error={errorFileds.includes(id)}
          id={id}
          type={"date"}
          // type={selectType(type)}
          isTextArea={inputFieldSettings[id]?.isTextArea}
          value={postRequestBody[selectedReport.report_id][id]}
          handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
          inputProps={{
            min: min.replace(" ", "T"),
            max: max.replace(" ", "T"),
          }}
        />
      );
```

NOW I DON'T KNOW WHY I RECEIVE THAT ERROR BECAUSE I CHANGED MANY THING IN THIS CODE BUT THE ERROR STILL REMINDS.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to have **"datetime-local"** you have to consider step in `inputProps` because in MUI by default it supports HH:MM so:

```
inputProps={{
  min: min.replace(" ", "T"),
  max: max.replace(" ", "T"),
  step: 1,
}}
```